# Shortest path in weighted graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a weighted graph $G(V,E)$ which edges could have negative values, and a source node $s$. There is no negative cycles in the graph and for each node $v$ there is a minimum weighted path from $s$ to it that uses **at most** $k$ edges.

Is there an algorithm that finds all minimum weighted paths in $k\cdot|E|$?

Answer (score 1):

Construct a layered graph with $k+1$ layers $0,\dots,k$, where each edge $(i,j)\in E$ corresponds to an edge from $(i,\ell)$ to $(j,\ell+1)$.  Now use breadth-first or depth-first search from $s$.

Comment: Can you show an example of your algorithm please? I don't think I got what you wrote ...